# DateTimePicker not showing value in View in ASP.NET MVC using EF Core [C#]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I'm currently experiencing unexpected behaviors of datetimepicker of my ASP.NET project.
I'm using a ViewModel `PartyViewModel` for `Create` and `Edit` actions while the `Party` model, which was scaffoled using EF Core is for read and passing data to the `PartyViewModel` only.

In `Edit.cshtml` View, the data for property `Date` is not displayed in the DateTimePicker while other properties are properly shown.

[Date value is not displayed in DateTimePicker](https://i.postimg.cc/3JfmMXmm/Screenshot-2023-11-07-123015.png)

My `.csproj` details :

- .NET 7
- ASP.NET Core MVC
- EntityFramework Core
- SQL Server Local DB
- ASP.NET Identity

My `Edit` action in `PartiesController.cs`:

```
// GET: Admin/Parties/Edit/5
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var party = await _context.Parties.FindAsync(id);

    if (party == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    PartyViewModel vm = new PartyViewModel(party);

    return View(vm);
}

// POST: Admin/Parties/Edit/5
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("PartyName,Quantity,Date,Time,Location,Note,Status,HasMenu,PartyTypeId,CustomerId")] 
PartyViewModel vm)
{
    var party = await _context.Parties.FindAsync(keyValues: id);

    if (party == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
    {
                _context.Entry(party).State = EntityState.Modified;
                                        // other props ...
                    party!.Date = vm.Date;
                    party!.Time = vm.Time;
                    // other props and foreign objects ...

            _context.Update(party);
            // Save changes
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!PartyExists(party.PartyId))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    return View(vm);
}
```

My `Edit.cshtml` view:

```
@model ASP.NET_Core_Website_QuanLyTiecCuoiLanHue.Areas.Admin.ViewModels.PartyViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Chỉnh sửa tiệc";
}

<!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
<div class="content-header">
<h1 class="m-0">@ViewData["Title"] / @Model.PartyName</h1>          
</div>


<!-- Main content -->

                <form method="edit" autocomplete="off">
                    <div class="form-group required">
                        <label asp-for="Date" class="control-label"></label>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "datetime-local"})
                        <span asp-validation-for="Date" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group required">
                        <label asp-for="Time" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Time" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Time" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" value="Lưu" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                </form>
<!-- /.content -->
```

My `PartyViewModel`:

```
[Keyless]
public class PartyViewModel
{

    // Date
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "{0} Không hợp lệ")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        // more annotations ...
    public DateTime? Date 
    { 
        get; set; 
    }
    // Time
    public TimeSpan? Time { get; set; }

    // other props ...

        // Constructors
    public PartyViewModel() { }
    public PartyViewModel(Party party) : this()
    {           
        // other props ...
        Date = party.Date!;
        Time = party.Time;
        // other props ...
    }
    public Party ToParty(QlDichVuNauTiecLanHueContext context)
    {
        return new Party()
        {
            // other props ...
            Date = Date,
            Time = Time,
            // other props ...
            // Foreign Objects
            PartyType = context.PartyTypes.Find(PartyTypeId) ?? new PartyType(),
            Customer = context.Customers.Find(CustomerId) ?? new Customer(),


        };
    }
}
```

My `Party` model:

```
[DisplayName("Tiệc")]
public partial class Party
{
    // other props ...

    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "{0} Không hợp lệ")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    // more annotations ...
    public DateTime? Date
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public TimeSpan? Time
    {
        get; set;
    }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual ICollection<Invoice> Invoices { get; set; } = new List<Invoice>();

    public virtual PartyType PartyType { get; set; } = null!;

    public virtual ICollection<Work> Works { get; set; } = new List<Work>();
}
```

Upon examining I found that the data from entity object `Party` from the `DbContext` is successfully passed to the `PartyViewModel` and I could view it in the console (red text)

[Data is displayed in the console](https://i.postimg.cc/0Q70PzPx/Screenshot-2023-11-07-121710.png)

I tried to change the display from an input type ( tag or @Html.TextBoxFor) to a plain text `@Html.DisplayFor` and the Date data is shown.

***How should I improve the situation?***

Is this the models design / object relation problem or anything else?

Comment: *"the data for property Date is not displayed in the DateTimePicker while other properties are properly shown."* and *"Data is displayed in the console"* suggest that this might be client side issue. is this `DateTimePicker` a js library or a HTML5 one?

Comment: the culprit is `(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"`, double check [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Date_and_time_formats#local_date_and_time_strings) for proper date format.

Answer (score 0):

It is an official design, DisplayFormat works for DisplayFor through TemplateHelpers, but others won’t. If you want to use TextBoxFor, add the format in html.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(modelItem => Model.ReleaseDate, "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", new {maxlength = 10})
```

And model attribute deleted

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
//[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
```

Page:

[image]